# How to use authblk in spanish?

Tags: languages, author

Whenever I try to use the `authblk` package the authors are separated by "and" instead of "y". I know you can change "and" for "und" if you include in the preamble

`\usepackage[german]{authblk}`

Nevertheless including the spanish option doesn't work. Is there a way around this. I really want to use `authblk` for my document!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The german option of the package just does

```
\DeclareOption{german}{\renewcommand\Authand{, und }%
                       \renewcommand\Authands{, und }}
```

But that is the only language option provided.

So in the preamble after loading the package you can do

```
\renewcommand\Authand{, y }
\renewcommand\Authands{, y }
```

or whatever you want.